# Select DISTINCT on different column than JOIN

Tags: sql-server, join, distinct

I've been messing around with this query for more than 8 hours and searching online and still can't get it to do what I need it to. So I'm hoping someone here can help

I'm basically trying to join two tables that are linked by a product ID, however, I only want to give the results of DISTINCT image IDs instead (which is not what it's joined by).

The tbl_images is a table that houses Unique numbers. And the ProductDetails table is a way that I can link those image IDs to a detail. Multiple product details can have the same image ID.

Here's my current query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT i.img_id, p.img_id AS detail_img_id  
FROM dbo.ProductDetails AS p  
INNER JOIN dbo.tbl_images AS i  
  ON p.ProductID = i.product_id  
WHERE (i.product_id = 22598)
```

If I only return `img_id` in my select it works fine, but I also need it to return the `detail_img_id` and this is where it starts to never work for me and return just the distinct row I need.

What I'm currently getting back is this:

```
+--------+---------------+
| img_id | detail_img_id |
+--------+---------------+
|   1916 |             0 |
|   1916 |          1916 |
|   1916 |          1917 |
|   1917 |             0 |
|   1917 |          1916 |
|   1917 |          1917 |
|   1918 |             0 |
|   1918 |          1916 |
|   1918 |          1917 |
+--------+---------------+
```

And I'd like it to return this below. If the image has never been assigned to any detail it should pull back a 0, if not, it can display some other number.

```
+--------+---------------+
| img_id | detail_img_id |
+--------+---------------+
|   1916 |          1916 |
|   1917 |          1917 |
|   1918 |             0 |
+--------+---------------+
```

Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: Can you describe your desired result in simple terms?  I'm having trouble understanding the relationship between the img_id and the detail_img_id.  Something like, "I want the detail_img_id that matches the img_id or 0 if there is no match."

Comment: I've got a table image ids and every one of them is unique. And then I can assign those images to any product detail. So there can be many product details with the same image ID.  So basically I'm looking for it to give me only the DISTINCT image ID that are in the image table AND if it's never been linked to a product detail than have it at 0, otherwise it can say 1 or some other #... just a way for me to know whether it's been linked to a detail or not basically.

Comment: Then why wouldn't you start w/ the image table LEFT join to the product details where product details image id is null?  You said you want any IMAGE that's not used right?

Comment: I want both used and unused images, but I need to know by the output whether they have been assigned or not. So I know for a fact that my image # 1918 has never been used on any product and should output 0, but it's not working that way. There is no null values in the database, either 0 by default or a number.

Comment: yes but null values will appear when you use an outer join from images to product detail because the image doesn't exist in product detail.

Comment: I'd realyl like to see the indexes/keys/fk's constraints on these two tables along with teh fields.  it seems like product and image should be part of the key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sound like you want all images, and those that match in product details.  and if no record in product details return 0 for the product image Id.

So... we outer join images to details and coalesce the p.image_ID to 0 so null values are converted to 0.

Just seems like you were missing join criteria to make it work. and a coalesce.

```
SELECT i.img_id, coalesce(p.img_id,0) AS detail_img_id  
FROM dbo.ProductDetails AS p  
RIGHT JOIN dbo.tbl_images AS i  
  on p.productID = i.product_ID
 and p.img_Id = i.img_Id
WHERE (i.product_id = 22598)
```

or if you're more comfortable with left joins...

```
SELECT i.img_id, coalesce(p.img_id,0) AS detail_img_id  
FROM JOIN dbo.tbl_images AS i  
LEFT JOIN dbo.ProductDetails AS p  
  on p.productID = i.product_ID
 and p.img_Id = i.img_Id
WHERE (i.product_id = 22598)
```

The duplication you were seeing in your results is becuase you were just joining on product_ID; I think you needed to include the image as well based on the fact both tables contain productID and both tables contain image.

Comment: Thank you. Your comment above led me in the right direction with the NULL values and I came up with something as well. Yours also led me to the same results. Thanks again!!

Comment: Definition of [xy problem.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/313572/prohibiting-to-ask-about-a-problem-rather-than-specific-solution-leads-to-xy-pro) asked about distinct and it was a coalesce/join issue! :P All good; glad we could help.  not a critique, just an observation in case others run across this.

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL Server doesn't have a `distinct on` syntax like PostgreSQL does, unfortunately (at least not that I'm aware of), but you can emulate this behavior with the `row_number` window function:

```
SELECT img_id, detail_img_id
FROM   (SELECT i.img_id AS img_id, 
               p.img_id AS detail_img_id
               ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY i.img_id
                                  ORDER BY p.img_id DESC) AS rn
        FROM   dbo.ProductDetails AS p
        JOIN   dbo.tbl_images AS i ON p.ProductID = i.product_id
        WHERE  i.product_id = 22598) t
WHERE   rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you, this is really close in that I'm getting the right amount of rows back for the img_id column, but it's setting all the detail_img_ids to 0.

Comment: @twentythree should have sorted the `row_number` descending, apologies. See my edited answer.

Comment: It's doing the opposite now and making all the detail_img_ids be a value of "1917". I think I'm confused about how this works. I have an images table that houses unique IDs and then a details table that I can assign those IDs too. So for instance my image # 1918 is never assigned to any detail. In theory that should show up as 0 in the output screen and not "1917" since it's never been assigned that value.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly but If I do it sounds like you need to use a left join:  The 0 in your desired result set throws me a bit so sorry if I misunderstood :)

Prep Work:

```
DECLARE @IM TABLE (id INTEGER)
DECLARE @DIM TABLE (did INTEGER)
INSERT INTO @IM
      select  1916
union all select  1916
union all select  1916
union all select  1917
union all select  1917
union all select  1917
union all select  1918
union all select  1918
union all select  1918     


INSERT INTO @DIM
        ( did )

  select    0
union all select 1916
union all select 1917
union all select    0
union all select 1916
union all select 1917
union all select    0
union all select 1916
union all select 1917
```

Yields

```
id
-----------
1916
1916
1916
1917
1917
1917
1918
1918
1918

(9 row(s) affected)

did
-----------
0
1916
1917
0
1916
1917
0
1916
1917

(9 row(s) affected)
```

Using:

```
SELECT i.id
    ,d.did
FROM @IM I
LEFT JOIN @dim D ON i.id = d.did
GROUP BY i.id
    ,d.did
```

Yields:

```
id          did
----------- -----------
1916        1916
1917        1917
1918        NULL

(3 row(s) affected)
```

With respect to your clarification:

```
DECLARE @IM TABLE (id INTEGER, did INTEGER)
INSERT INTO @IM (id, did)
      select      1916,  0
union all select  1916, 1916 
union all select  1916, 1917
union all select  1917,    0
union all select  1917, 1916
union all select  1917, 1917
union all select  1918,    0
union all select  1918, 1916
union all select  1918, 1917  

SELECT id, x.maxdid AS MaxDiD
FROM @im i
OUTER APPLY (SELECT MAX(did) AS maxdid FROM @im i2 WHERE i2.id = i.id) x
GROUP BY id, maxdid
```

Comment: OP requires distinct of two columns separately

Comment: This isn't working for me because it's not joined on those id numbers that I gave. It's joined on a different ProductID column.

Comment: So you would like two separate lists?  one for ID and one for DID or you want them both in 1 query answer?  What if there are more individual ID values than DID values?

Comment: I'm hoping the results can be returned in one query. And yes, there are DID values with the same ID values multiple times. I'm hoping that if all the DID values for ID are 0, then it returns 0, and that if any of the DID values return not 0, it'll display some other # (doesn't really matter what). Thank you